# Where to put user access controls? The controller or the model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, design-patterns

I understand that we're supposed to avoid putting logic in the controller. So what is the proper way to implement things like user access controls. Let's suppose I have `User`, where each instance has a flag method `admin?` that determines whether the user can access information from other users.

---

### Option 1: Put access controls in custom model

Model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.get_list(accessor)
    return [] unless accessor.admin?
    self.all
  end
end
```

Controller:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @users = User.get_list(current_user)
  end
end
```

`current_user` would probably be defined somewhere in the application controller.

### Option 2: Put access controls in the controller

Model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

Controller:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @users = current_user.admin? User.all : []
  end
end
```

There are also some peripheral consequences such as where tests go and how they're implemented.

---

My instinct is that the first of the two options is preferable, but I've only ever used option 2 in the past. Also, it seems like the generally accepted (as far as I can tell) practice of putting on action-wide access filters is done at the controller level as in:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :verify_logged_in
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any logic controlling routing of your application belongs in your controller. As for your example, the first is preferable but really there's not much in it.

It's easy for opinionated frameworks make us almost obsessive about doing things in a perceived correct way. In your example such a tiny amount of logic would, in my opinion, be perfectly fine to leave in your controller. If you were to abstract it, give it a descriptive name that described better what the method is doing otherwise you're simply making your code needlessly difficult to read.

Answer (score 0):

As a *rails rookie*, the second option to me seems far easier to read and comphrehend. I prefer how I can read the single line in the controller and see exactly what you are doing.

In the first example, this logic is hidden someplace else (obviously the model, but I'm a rookie remember!) and seems slightly verbose (for this particular example).

*I don't mean to suggest keeping it easier for new kids is A Good Thing, just pointing out a preference.*